# Using video.js in angular.js directive

Tags: video, angularjs, video.js

This directive is supposed to watch for changes in the scope.tutorialNumber variable (which increases as the user progresses through tutorials) and then load the new video by using tutorialNumber as an index on the array videoURLs, which then replace the first one which is hardcoded into the html. However the $watch doesn't seem to get triggered at all when tutorialNumber is updated. Why?

```
<video data-setup="{'techOrder': ['html5', 'flash']}"  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" id="myvideo" video-loader="tutorialNumber" id="video" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/grammar%20game/ㅗㅏregular.mp4"></source> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

.directive('videoLoader', function(){
    return function (scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch(scope.tutorialNumber, function(){          
                //element.load();           
                scope.video.src(scope.videoURLs[scope.tutorialNumber]);
                scope.video.ready(function(){
                scope.video.play();
                $(scope.video).bind('ended', function(){
                    $(scope.video).unbind('ended');
                    if (!scope.video.ended) {
                        return;
                    }
                    scope.tutorialNumber++;
                    scope.$apply();
                    scope.loadFromMenu();
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your video tag has two IDs, just a note.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your $watch expression as:

```
scope.$watch('tutorialNumber', function(){ ...
```

or

```
scope.$watch(function(){return scope.tutorialNumber;}, function(){ ...
```

Comment: tried that and the video doesn't even load the first time, let alone on change

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fDOrF3UHj5ulubSanxfu?p=preview although this one is completely broken...

Comment: Your Plunker froze when I tried searching for 'tutorialNumber'. Would be great if you could reduce it to the bare minimum that still reproduces the problem in question.

Comment: I can really take anything out, it's all dependent on everything working, and what I put into Plunker works in my browser but not in Plunker. TBH I'm thinking video.js was just a failed experiment. This works for me though http://plnkr.co/edit/fDOrF3UHj5ulubSanxfu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Am I reading this wrong, or are your scope references written wrong?

You have `scope` listed in most cases, but the common Angular reference is `$scope`.

Also, there is such a thing as `$rootScope`. You can utilize `$rootScope` to return values to the parent of the application (model) and then utilize $scope inside directives or modules to compartmentalize the data.